# How to set the lower or higher Value of a int64?

Tags: c++, int64

I know i can get the higher Value of a int 64 with:

```
int32 higher = (int32)(iGUID >> 32);
```

But how can i set it?

I tried it with this, but it says "expression must be a modifiable value":

```
iGUID << 32 = inewlGUID;
```

I need to keep the other Value, ( if i set the higher value, the lower should keep).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the upper 32 bits while keeping the lower ones unmodified:

```
iGUID = (iGUID & 0xFFFFFFFF) | (inewlGUID << 32);
```

Comment: 'iGUID & 0xFFFFFFFF' zeros all the upper section bits. right?

Answer (score 0):

```
iGUID = (static_cast<int64>(inewlGUID) << 32) | (iGUID & 0xffffffff);
```

This will preserve any existing contents.

You can also take the address of the 64 bit value and cast it to a pointer to `int32`, which can then be subscripted and assigned to. This is usually *not* recommended, however, because it will make your code depend on the platform's byte order.